# SQL: Select all records in table that exist in a select query where there is a composite key

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to select all records from a table that also exist in a select query. The table in this case has a composite key. I want something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE 
(FOO, BAR) IN
SELECT...
```

Where `(FOO, BAR)` is my composite key and `SELECT...` is a select query. How should I alter the above to get it to work?

Comment: I would say "SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE 
(FOO, BAR) IN
(SELECT what you want)"

Comment: You already used the word EXISTS: `select ... from a where exists (select * from b where b.x = ... AND ...);`

Comment: @user2196728 SQLite doesn't support tuple comparisons.

Comment: ok sorry, i didn't paid attention that it was SQLite related, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you are looking for is `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table] A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FOR [SomeTable] B 
              WHERE A.FOO = B.FOO AND A.BAR = B.BAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
JOIN (SELECT...
) AS a 
ON Table.FOO=a.FOO AND Table.BAR=a.BAR
```

Comment: A join will return additional records if multiple records in the child table match that condition - `EXISTS` is a more appropriate solution here.

Comment: Yes, I suppose my reflex in those cases is just `GROUP BY Table.ID`.  I suppose in rare cases this might not exist and/or be obvious.  (for some reason I'm opposed to `EXISTS`, I tend to prefer `(SELECT 1 ...)`.